# How to get MongoClient object from Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have to get the `MongoClient` object from mongoose connection object, so that I can reuse for `Agenda` or somewhere else where I need.

**db.js**

```
// Export the mongoose instance
module.exports = () => {
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
  try {
    console.log('DBURL:', dbConfig.url);
    const { url, options } = dbConfig;
    mongoose
      .connect(url, options)
      .then(() => console.log('DB Connected'), err => console.log(err, options));

    mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
      logger.log('info', 'Mongoose default connection opened');
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
      // logger.log('error',  'Couldn't able to connect to MongoDB', err);
      // Blow system on db error
      logger.log('info', 'Mongoose default connection opened');
      throw err;
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('reconnected', () => {
      logger.log('info', 'Mongo connection reconnected', arguments);
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('disconnecting', () => {
      logger.log('error', 'Mongoose connection disconnecting', arguments);
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
      logger.log('error', 'Mongoose connection disconnected', arguments);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Couldn't connect to mongo:", e);
  }

  return mongoose;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the mongoClient with `getClient()` method as shown in the docs: [getClient()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-getClient)

Basically you need to do something like this

```
const client = mongoose.connection.getClient()
```

So to use it with connect-mongo for example you could just export that from your *db.js* then import and use where needed.

```
//db.js
module.exports.client = mongoose.connection.getClient()

//app.js
const { client } = require('path to file')
const store = MongoStore.create({ client })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
let options = { //Your options };
const mongoClient = new mongoose.mongo.MongoClient(URI, options)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
config = require('./configs');
mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = function() {
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db, config.mongoDBOptions).then(
    () => {
        console.log('MongoDB connected')
    },
    (err) => {
        console.log('MongoDB connection error',err)
    }
    );

require('../app/models/xxx.server.model');
require('../app/models/yyy.server.model');
return db;};
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, mongoose.connect() returns a promise which resolves to the Mongoose instance. OP is looking for the underlying MongoClient instance.

Answer (score -1):

You may get MongoClient Object by following this method:

```
const { MongoClient, ObjectID } = require('mongodb');

 function(req, res) {
 (async function mongo() {
      let client;
      try {
        client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true});
        debug('Connected correctly to server');

        const db = client.db(dbName);
}
```

Comment: This creates a MongoClient instance, it does not get the MongoClient instance from mongoose.